# controle service on remote server with custom c# utility

Tags: c#, service

I have a problem I hope you bright guys can answer for me:

On server “A” I have a service running that sometimes needs to be stopped or restarted for reasons I can’t control. The service is run by a dedicated network user, say “serviceusr”, that is a member of the domain.

The problem is, that in some installations, server “A” resides in a hosted environment without direct access to server “A”. I have access to server “B” through RDP, that resides on the same network and in the same domain.

**My idea is to create a small utility in C# that can be installed on server “B” that can impersonate “serviceusr” on Server “A” to start and stop the service. The “serviceusr” must have rights granted access to start and stop the service, and this is no problem to obtain.**

I have scoured the internet for hints and samples that could lead me on the right track, but haven’t found the “holy grail” yet. I have found a number of samples that claims to be able to do the job, but none have done the trick. I tried to tweak and/or combine them to the best of my abilities without any further progress. It seems to me that it isn’t possible to impersonate “servieusr” on server “A” from server “B”.

**My question to you are: Is my idea even possible?**

And if it is, all kinds of hints, links or sample code on how to implement would be really great.

Thanks for the help in advance

/Morny

Comment: How are you stopping and starting the service right now? That might help someone point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm currently loging on to Server A as administrator and handle start and stop manually. The aim is to make it possible for a non administrative user to start and stop the service without logging on to the server themselfe.